# Java not opening PDF

Tags: java, user-interface, debugging, intellij-idea, path

Attempting to have a button in my Java GUI open a PDF. My PDF is in the src folder, the same folder where my code is but I get a 'file not found' error and am unsure what is wrong with my pathing.

```
        aboutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    try {
                        File aboutPDF = new File("./aboutGUI.pdf");
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(aboutPDF);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: put it in your resources folder depending how you are setup you can just do "aboutGUI.pdf" once it is in resources folder otherwise you would do src/main/resources or whatever your path is.

Comment: Are you sure that `/src/aboutGUI.pdf` is the right (absolute) file path? Did you try logging the exception instead of just ignoring it?

Comment: @jb31 I also tried doing  ```./aboutGUI.pdf ``` since it is in the same folder (src) but that didn't' work either.

Comment: @c2h50h that worked! thank you.

Comment: No problem I'll place it as an answer thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to put it in your resources folder as that is where your IDE looks by default for files unless specified otherwise. Then do "filename.pdf" or "src/main/resources/filename.pdf"